# Android Studio imports multiple projects into a single one

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a top-level folder which acts as a `workspace`, so it contains all my `projects`.

Here, by `project`, I mean a standalone `app`, nothing else. So the `workspace` contains multiple separate `apps`, not linked by any means.

A `project` can have a single `module`, or multiple `modules` if needed (I have projects of both types).

The problem is that, when I tried today to import a `project`, it not only imported the one I wanted, it also imported along with it, another 2 projects from the same `workspace`... into the same project layout in AS. So now I have 3 `apps` showing up as the same `project`. That's not cool. I presume AS mistakenly thought the other 2 `projects` were `modules` related to the project I selected initially.

I also want to add the fact that the import succeeded on another computer. I've also tried invalidating the AS cache and restarting it. Same problem.

If you don't have a solution for importing ONLY the project I need (though this would be great), at least can somebody give me a solution for deleting the other 2 projects ?
I have a delete option on them, but apparently it deletes them from disk as well.

Comment: Pfff...... after I deleted the other projects as I said above, then restarted AS, the wanted project didn't stay as hoped. No. Apparently the WHOLE FREAKING workspace appeared as the main project, with all the ACTUAL projects under it. This is seriously messed up :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I'm answering my own question. This isn't an actual answer as to why this freakish event happened, but more of a solution.

Just completely delete the affected projects from disk, then clone them again from remote. Import should work fine now. I have no idea why, but whatever...